# Continue formulas automatically

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with columns A-J. Column A-F is filled manually while columns G-J is calculated based on values from A-F.

When filling rows with data in columns A-F, the cells in column G automatically fills with the correct formula while I have to manually "drag" colums H-J down to make them repeat down the rows.

Is there a way of making columns H-J behave like column G. And why is column G behaving like this?

I have the option "extend data range formats and formulas" turned ON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why your sheet is behaving as it is, but if you format the data as a data table then it will behave as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried some of the tutorials on data tables, but as far as I can tell this solution does not allow inserting rows. This is a must for me. Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Would it be possible to explain how I would format the entire existing dataset as a data table?

Comment: To create a data table from your existing data, just select it all, go to Insert on the ribbon, click Table. A dialog will come up asking if your table has headers - tell it yes or no. Then your table will be created. Then if you insert a row in the table, or add extra data at the bottom of the table, your formulae and formats will be copied automatically into the new row or rows.

Comment: Great. Worked like a charm. Thanks!